# Loop tuples inside a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to make Morse code with Python, so I tried the following:

```
L = [(2, 1), (8, 4, 2, 1)]    
data = "00:1:02"
data = [(x[:1], x[1:]) for x in data.split(':') ]
for [a,b] in data:
    if b=="": b, a = a, '0'
    #print(a,b)
```

Now, I am looking for a simple way to loop trough the two tuples in the `L` list and separate them to make the `a` pass trough `L[0]` tuple and `b` pass though `L[1]` tuple.

Something like that in one for loop:

```
for A in l[0], B in l[1]:

#A to do somethings with a and 
#B to do something with b
```

I tried some combines but I didn't find the right syntax. Can any one offer any suggestions?

Comment: In your example the tuples within `L` are not the same length, what behavior do you want when `L[0]` has been exhausted but there are still more elements in `L[1]`?

Comment: Its a problem. that's why my combines doesn't work. i need that "a" will get check in twice and "b" four times. but I want to do it with less lines of codes. that why i get so complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate over `L[0]` and `L[1]` at the same time you can use:

```
for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(L[0], L[1]):
    print a, b
```

The above will set `a` to `None` as `L[1]` is longer than `L[0]` and thus there are more values in `L[1]` to iterate over than in `L[0]`. This gives:

```
2 8
1 4
None 2
None 1
```